# Does eternal functional subordination replace the two natures theory?

Tags: hypostatic-union, subordinationism

It seems as if everybody accepts that the Bible represents the Son as subordinate to the Father. For example, in Gethsemane, Jesus prayed to his Father, “yet not as I will, but as You will” (Matt 26:39).

However, people identify different types of subordination and regard certain types of subordination as consistent with equality and others not.

One type of subordination was [the two natures theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalcedonian_Definition) that was formulated at Chalcedon in 451. In this, following the [Hypostatic union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostatic_union#:%7E:text=Hypostatic%20union%20%28from%20the%20Greek%3A%20%E1%BD%91%CF%80%CF%8C%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B1%CF%83%CE%B9%CF%82%20hyp%C3%B3stasis%2C%20%22sediment%2C,is%20Jesus%20Christ%20being%20both%20God%20and%20man.), **the one person of Jesus Christ has two distinct natures**, human and divine. ([Two natures of Jesus | Theopedia](https://www.theopedia.com/hypostatic-union)). And His statements of subordination, such as that He does not know the day and hour of His return, but only the Father (Matt 24:36), were made from His inferior human nature. As the Athanasian Creed states,

> “Equal to the Father, as touching his Godhead;  and inferior to the
> Father as touching his Manhood.”

Consequently, “He will always and forever exist in heaven as a glorified man, albeit God at the same time” ([Two natures of Jesus | Theopedia](https://www.theopedia.com/hypostatic-union)).

However, the two natures theory only explains the subordination of the Son after His incarnation while the Bible says that the Son always was subordinate to the Father. For example:

- The Father sent the Son, gave Him what to do and what to say (John 6:38; 8:42; 12:49; 17:4).
- The Father created the Universe “through” the Son (Heb 1:1-2).

Furthermore, the Bible says that **the Person of the Son** (not only His human nature) will always be subordinate to the Father. For example:

- God created all things “through” His Son (Heb 1:1-2) and, when all sin and consequences of sin have been removed from creation, the Son Himself also will be subjected to God so that God may be all in all (1 Cor 15:28).
- Statements such as that “God is the head of Christ” (1 Cor 11:3) and that the Father is His God (Eph 1:3; Rev 3:12) refer to Him as a Person; not to one of His two natures only.

Therefore, another type of subordination that is suggested is an eternal functional subordination between the Persons, including that the Son is eternally subordinate to the Father:

> “The subordination of the person of the Son to the person of the
> Father … which permits the Father to be officially first, the Son
> second, and the Spirit third, is perfectly consistent with equality.”
> (Augustus Strong (1836 – 1921) Systematic Theology, Volume 3)
>
> “All three Persons of the Godhead are equal in nature. … What the
> Bible does teach is an economic (or relational) subordination within
> the Trinity. The three Persons of the triune Godhead voluntarily
> submit to each other respecting the roles They perform in creation and
> salvation.” ([GotQuestions](https://www.gotquestions.org/subordination-Trinity.html))
>
> Hodge maintained that “In the Holy Trinity there is a subordination of
> the Persons in relation to the mode of subsistence and operation.” For
> example, he says, while it is true that “The Father sends the Son” and
> that “The Father operates through the Son,” still “the Son is never
> said to send the Father, nor to operate through him.” (Reformed
> Theologian Charles Hodge (1797 – 1878), Systematic Theology, Grand
> Rapids, Eerdmans, 1952, p445)
>
> “Some have sought to interpret biblical passages that speak of the Son
> submitting to or being subject to that Father as only describing a
> temporary, less than ideal state of affairs … Any possibility of the
> submission of the Son to the Father being a temporary or less than
> ideal state of affairs seems out of the question here (1 Cor 15:28).” [Glenn Peoples](http://www.rightreason.org/2012/nuts-and-bolts-014-relational-subordination-within-the-trinity/))

My question is, does this second type of subordination replace the two natures theory? Does it explain all indications of subordination that we find in the Bible, or is the two natures theory still required to explain some indications of subordination that are not explained by eternal functional subordination?

Comment: Can you give a link to a clear definition of "eternal functional subordination"? I'm not sure exactly what it means, but if it is incompatible with the hypostatic union, then it would be considered heretical by Nicene/Chalcedonian Christians (ie, the majority today.)

Comment: But you're mistaken if you think the primary reason for the hypostatic union is to explain passages that suggest a subordination. The primary purpose of the doctrine of the hypostatic union is to explain the passages indicating both the divinity and humanity of Christ. So many Christians who reject subordinationism will still see the necessity of the hypostatic union.

Comment: @curiousdannii Hi, I added quotes in the question to explain "eternal functional subordination." Hope that helps. Just a note - you refer to "the majority." I hope you are not saying the majority is right. Was there ever a time in history, as recorded in the Bible, that the majority was right? Did the majority not kill the prophets and the Messiah? To be among the majority, I believe, might be comfortable on this earth, but, for eternal life, it is a very dangerous place to be.

Comment: @curiousdannii I agree with your second comment. However, I would prefer to say that the Chalcedonian symbol was an adaptation of the Nicene Creed which already defined the Son as fully divine. Hanson describes the two natures theory as drawing back from the full drastic consequences of the Nicene Creed (of the full divinity of Christ) under the influence of a Greek fear of compromising God with human experiences.

Comment: The majority does not define truth, but it does set expectations on the strength of arguments required to overturn it. Some times the majority has very poor arguments, but this is not one of those times. And if you believe that God works through his Church then abandoning Chalcedon is not lightly done. I don't know who Hanson is, but nothing about Chalcedon draws back from the full divinity of Christ.

Comment: Since 'Father' and 'Son' are the concepts uttered by Deity to reveal Deity, why do you have such a problem with the _relative_ relationships and the _inherent_ attitudes of a Son to a Father and a Father to a Son ? Human fatherhood and human sonship only exist because the _reality_ is true of Deity. I think the question needs a good deal more _clarity_ as to what exactly you have a problem with in the _scriptural_ expression of Fatherhood and Sonship.

Comment: @curiousdannii Kevin Giles described RPC Hanson's book - The Search For The Christian Doctrine Of God - as his “definitive book on Arianism.” Both  Bishop Rowan Williams and  Dr. Hart, lecturer in Systematic Theology stated that nothing comparable exists in either scale or erudition exists in the English language. See [Real Issue](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/88801/what-was-the-real-issue-at-nicaea-in-325) for links.

Comment: @Andries Sure, but this question isn't about Arianism, and an expert on Arianism is not automatically an expert on Chalcedon.

Comment: @NigelJ This question is not about what I think is the right view. This question is simply about the different types of subordination that people define - ontological, economic, functional, relational, and perhaps also others. I am trying to make sense of the different types or subordination and how they relate.

Comment: No. You asked 'does it replace the two natures theory' ? It is not _simply about the different types_. You are seeking to set aside the duality of nature of Christ. And you do so by questioning subordination and its relational reality in the _relationship of the Father to the Son and the Son to the Father_

Comment: @NigelJ Perhaps your analogy of a human father and son to the Divine Father and Son is useful in this question. I assume that Jesus used those titles as metaphors to say something about His relationship with His Father. A human son is ontologically equal to his father but functionally subordinate. Whereas a human father dies, the divine Father never dies. Therefore eternal functional subordination.

Comment: You confuse 'function' with 'loving relationship'. I wonder why that is ?

Comment: You might wish that the eternal, functional subordination theory you are promoting would replace the two natures [of Christ] theory, but it doesn't. It can only be an alternative theory. You are asking for support for this alternative theory as you want answers from those who think it does, but you don't state that you are seeking answers from such a group. Yet you are. If you are not, then you are seeking an argument critical of the theory you are out to promote. You could answer your own question yourself.

Comment: @anne Eternal, functional subordination is standard theology. See A defense of the doctrine of the eternal subordination of the son by Stephen D. Kovach and Peter R. Schemm, jr. Journal of the evangelical theological society 42/3 (september 1999) 461–476

Comment: @curiousdannii You stated: "So many Christians who reject subordinationism will still see the necessity of the hypostatic union." That seems like stating the obvious. Is that what you wanted to say? Or did you intend to say that "So many Christians who accept that the Son is subordinate will still see the necessity of the hypostatic union?"

Comment: Sure. As I said in my answer, they're orthogonal.

Comment: "The Father created the Universe “through” the Son (Heb 1:1-2)." Literally, the 'ages'. So understanding Heb 1:2 depends on what you think the context is. Clause before it is talking about him being appointed heir. When? In the new creation. So perhaps the ages being referred to are the Messianic Ages.

Answer (score 4):

Both [Eastern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Orthodox_Church) and [Oriental Orthodox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oriental_Orthodox_Churches) churches believe in the *eternal hypostatic subordination* of the only-begotten Son to His everlasting Father; however, [the former](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalcedonian_Christianity) affirm [two natures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyophysitism) in Christ, whereas [the latter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Chalcedonian_Christianity) confess to [just one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miaphysitism).

The [Roman Catholic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catholic_Church) and [traditionally Protestant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protestantism) churches, on the other hand, whilst also following [Chalcedon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_Chalcedon)'s wholesale rejection and condemnation of [Monophysitism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monophysitism), nevertheless espouse certain [scholastic views](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scholasticism), partially at odds with the theology of the other two ancient and apostolic churches, best captured by an omission in the aforementioned quotation from the [Athanasian creed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athanasian_Creed):

> Equal to the Father, as touching his Godhead; and inferior to the Father as touching his Manhood.

What matters here is not so much what is actually being said in the statement, but rather what is conspicuously absent from it, namely *timeless personal obedience* of the other two divine hypostases towards the one God and Father, their equality of nature notwithstanding.

Comment: I think that your answer is very important. I realized that when I recently read in Paul Pavao that Eastern Orthodox Christians represent at least half of Christian tradition after Nicea. You state that both Eastern and Oriental Orthodox churches “believe in the eternal hypostatic subordination of the only-begotten Son to His everlasting Father.” I understand that to mean that the hypostasis (person) of the Son is subordinate to the hypostasis (person) of the Father. We Westerners should not assume that we have all the right answers.

Comment: @Andries I do not think that Jesus' hypostasis was only begotten Son and Everlasting Father.  The Hypostasis was Human being and eternally begotten Son and therefore the subordination can be understood as being of the entire hypostasis to God the Father.

Answer (score 4):

To my mind, the two issues are orthogonal.

The questions of the relationship between the Father and Son and whether or not the Son is eternally generated, whether the Father has authority over the Son, whether the Father is above the Son only in their work in the universe or also ontologically, these are all questions that monophysites must deal with also.

On the other hand, the questions of the nature of the union between God and man in the person of Christ, to what extent he had a human nature, whether Christ has any dual faculties, whether the divine nature is limited by the human nature and whether the human nature obtains omni- characteristics from the divine nature, these are all questions that need to be answered regardless of whether you think that it is right or wrong to say the Son is subordinate to the Father.

So no, no theory of subordination replaces the doctrine of the two natures of Christ. The two natures of Christ are not recognised in order to resolve the passages that appear to show the subordination of the Son under the Father, but to resolve the passages which show the full divinity and the full humanity of Christ.

Answer (score 4):

Yesterday, when I again read in the Chalcedonian Creed that the Son is homoousios (of the same substance) as God AND homoousios (of the same substance) as man, I realized what the answer to my question is. My question involves a category error. There are different categories of equality/inferiority:

- Ontological (Essence or substance)
- Relational (Begotten, implying that the Father is the Ultimate Source of all things)
- Functional (role)

Since the two natures theory addresses the substance of the being of the Son and the Father, it deals only with the first category while eternal functional subordination deals only with the third. Eternal functional subordination, therefore, does not replace the two natures theory because these are different categories of things.

I think Curiousdanni makes the same point when he says that these two matters are orthogonal (at right angles with one another) and when he says that the two natures theory does not explain the subordination of the Son; it explains how the Son can be both human and divine.

I think Lucian also made the same point when he quotes the Athanasian Creed:

> Equal to the Father, as touching his Godhead; and inferior to the
> Father as touching his Manhood.

And points out that that states “their equality of nature” but does not address the matter of “obedience.”